# Redshift Comments on Constraints

Tags: amazon-redshift

Redshift doesn't support constraints then why does it support comments on constraints.

Quoting From the [redshift documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COMMENT.html)

```
 COMMENT ON
 {
 TABLE object_name |
 COLUMN object_name.column_name |
 CONSTRAINT constraint_name ON table_name |
 DATABASE object_name |
 VIEW object_name
 }
 IS 'text'
```

How to retrieve the comments for constraints from the database in this case?
 What system views to use?

Comment: You can [declare constraints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html) but they are not enforced. So it seems to make sense that you can create comments on them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name----Then how to retrieve comments for constraints

Comment: what is the point of this question? what is your use case that you cannot achieve?

Comment: You can view comments in the pg_catalog.pg_description system catalog, but as others have mentioned, what is it you are trying to accomplish by doing this? While redshift does not enforce unique constraints they are used in the query planner and can be referenced for ETL processes.

Comment: @Andrew.....the pg_catalog.pg_description system catalog gives the objoid of the constraint different from the one that we get in pg_index or pg_class or pg_attribute catalogs. Because of that i wasnt able to retrieve the comments for constraints. Now i have modified the query to use pg_constraint catalog which gives same objoid in both case.